# How can I compose this query?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem coming up with a query in MySQL. I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  tm.ticket_message_id, 
  tm.ticket_id, 
  tm.message_from, 
  tm.message_to, 
  t.member_id, 
  t.member_to 
FROM 
  `ticket_messages` AS tm 
  INNER JOIN `tickets` AS t 
  ON ( t.ticket_id = tm.ticket_id )
```

The primary key of table `ticket_messages` is `ticket_message_id`. For `tickets`, the primary key is `ticket_id`.

Right now, due to a mistake in a program's logic, the value in `ticket_messages.message_from` is always 0. This is wrong.

Now I must fix this situation and set `tm.message_to` to `tm.message_to` or `t.member_id`, depending on the following condition:

Suppose `ID_1` and `ID_2` are two IDs. If `tm.message_from` and `t.member_to` are both equal to `ID_1`, and `t.member_id` is equal to `ID_2`, then the value for `tm.message_from` needs to be assigned the value in `t.member_id`.

If `tm.message_from` and `t.member_id` are equal to `ID_2`, and `t.member_to` is equal to `ID_1`, then the value for `tm.message_from` needs to be assigned the value in `t.member_to`.

How I could fix my table with a MySQL query?

Comment: Note to other editers: I am going to attempt to clean this one up.

Comment: Alright, I'm done editing it. I hope I didn't lose any information. I'm not 100% clear on the conditions kofto4ka has listed, so I left them more or less how I found them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the awesome "CASE" statement.

```
UPDATE `ticket_messages` AS tm, `tickets` AS t
SET tm.message_from = CASE
  WHEN tm.message_from == t.member_id THEN t.member_id
  ELSE t.member_to
END
WHERE ( t.ticket_id = tm.ticket_id )
```

Comment: No "UPDATE ... FROM" in mysql.

Comment: I think that the right syntax is next:
UPDATE `ticket_messages` tm
INNER JOIN `tickets` AS t ON ( t.ticket_id = tm.ticket_id )
SET tm.message_from = CASE
  WHEN tm.message_from = t.member_id THEN t.member_id
  ELSE t.member_to
END

But it doesnt affect any rows.

Comment: Good point.  I've updated it to what I think is proper mysql syntax.  I'm used to thinking in SqlServer.